# Openning a link in mu4e message

Tags: mu4e

How do I open a hyperlink in an mu4e message? I know I can click on it, but is there a keyboard shortcut I can press or a function I can call to open the link? I don't like using the mouse when I don't have to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`g` will prompt you for a url to visit, which you select by number. (The numbers appear next to the link in the message)

From mu4e you can open the manual at any time with `H`. This will open the manual at the section for whichever view you were in - main, headers, message, editor. To find out what you can do with an individual message you need the `Message View` section. Check out the `keybindings` page for a quick overview of the most frequent commands you'll want to use.

Comment: Not all my email messages show numbers next to their links; I'm not sure what this depends on.  If not, I can get to the desired link by pressing `TAB` and open it with `ENTER`.  However, if urls are numbered, I can use `k` to copy them to the kill ring.  The manual does not give an alternative for unnumbered links.

Comment: @AstroFloyd yes, it's the same for me. I suspect it has to do with plain text vs html messages, but I'm not at my computer to check

Comment: When I jump to an unnumbered link with `TAB`, I can see the url in the echo area.  Do you know a way to copy it directly from the mu4e message view (instead of clicking on the echo area to open the Messages buffer, jumping there and copying it)?

Comment: @AstroFloyd as I recall, you can tab to the link you want, then press enter to open it. You don't need to click on the minibuffer

Comment: That is correct, but it will often open in the wrong Firefox profile and then redirect to some url with an error statement.  I need to copy it and paste it in the correct Firefox instance...